# Analyse grammaticale (La Peste, Albert Camus)

Tags: grammaire, appositions

Quelle est la fonction grammaticale du syntagme nominal après la seconde virgule ? S'agit-il d'une coordination asyndétique de deux parties d'un complément de présentatif (« c'était ») ? S'agit-il d'une apposition ? Serait-ce autre chose ?

> (*La Peste*, Albert Camus) Au-dehors, c’était la même nuit froide, des étoiles
> gelées dans un ciel clair et glacé.

Answer (score 1):

Je pencherais pour une [asyndète](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynd%C3%A8te), plutôt qu'une [apposition](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition#Statut_grammatical_de_l%E2%80%99apposition), car il n'y a pas "identité de référence avec le terme auquel l'apposition est associée". Le sens est clair, Camus donne des précisions sur la *nuit froide*: elle est remplie d'*étoiles gelées dans un ciel clair et glacé*.